# Perl Template with strict option: how to check whether a variable is defined?

Tags: perl

The following code dies with a var.undef error because `var` is not defined. It works if I change the `STRICT` option to 0, but I'd like to keep strict checks, unless it's in an `[% IF var %]` check in the template. How do I do that?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;

my $t = Template->new(STRICT => 1) || die Template->error();
my $template = '[% IF var %][% var %][% END%]';
my $output = '';
$t->process(\$template, {}, \$output) || die $t->error(), "\n";
print "$output\n";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending in an empty hash reference that doesn't contain the `var` variable that you're asking the template to display.

You can either check in your Perl code to set a sane default (in this example, I just hard-code it into the call to `process()`):

```
$t->process(\$template, {var => 55}, $output) || die $t->error(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
55
```

...or, you can tell the template to set its own sane default if the `var` variable isn't sent on the way in (ie, it's undefined):

```
my $template = '[% DEFAULT var = "sane" %][% IF var %][% var %][% END%]';
```

Output:

```
sane
```

Comment: Great, thanks, I hoped there was a shorter way but this works and the default does not get placed in the actual hash on the Perl side (no side effect).

Comment: Personally, I would *highly* recommend doing your variable vetting within the code itself. The template shouldn't have to do its own error management. Things should be pristine being sent to the template, so write something in Perl that verifies that all template variables are satisfied. Template checking like this could cause issues; don't blame the paperwork if you've signed it blindly

Comment: Agreed, especially cause I can write unit tests for anything in Perl much easier than for the templates. My situation was with optional data in a domain object. I did not want to duplicate them to variables for the template, and I did not want to enter dummy values for optional data.